# executing php scripts in node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, apache

I have set up an apache and node server with the following settings...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot C:\Apache24\htdocs
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost:3000
DocumentRoot C:\Apache24\htdocs\mynodeapp
    ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
</Location>
```

I am struggling to get a php script to work in the mynodeapp directory, the error I get is...

```
Cannot GET /mynodeapp/index.php
```

I would like to ask, would I need to install additional modules in node or is there a way to execute php scripts in node with my current settings? what would be the correct way to do this?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you tried to GET `/mynodeapp/` only?

Comment: i'm still getting an error Cannot GET /mynodeapp/